# .pyc files generated in different folder

Tags: python, module, compilation, installation, distribution

Friends,

I was trying to create a python distribution. I executed the commands:
python setup.py sdist followed by python setup.py install
but the distribution created showed up folders build and dist without .pyc file.
Then I tried to find that file using windows find and got that its present in 
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

Could anybody tell me the mistake I did in setup or missed anything.

Thanks in advance,
Saurabh

Comment: That's normal behavior. Is it causing you some kind of problem?

Comment: Not as such but if I want to compile like a lot of files then i have to copy paste from 1 location to other. Also, I am a beginner in python. If windows find was not there it would have been impossible for me to get them. I would have thought that my python is not working properly. In fact, initially i thought it that way. I was planning to replace python27 to python3.

Comment: Why do you need the .pyc files? They will be created when needed. BTW, .pyc files from Python 2.7 won't run with Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

`sdist` command creates a source distribution that should not and does not contain pyc files.

`install` command installs in your local environment. Creating Python distributions is not its purpose.

If your package is pure Python then the source distribution is enough to install it anywhere you like; you don't need pyc files that depend on Python version and thus less general. `bdist` or `bdist_egg` (setuptools) generate among other things pyc files.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any pyc files until the first time you run the module.  A source distribution is just that.  Distributing pyc files is not usually useful anyway, they are not portable.  If you intended to *only* distribute pyc files then you are in for a lovely set of problems when different python versions, and different operating systems, are used.  Always distribute the source.

For most modules, the time taken to generate them the first time they are used is trivial - it is not worth worrying about.

By the way, when you move to Python 3, the pyc files are now stored in a directory called `__pycache__` (3.2).